# how to set_error_handler so it can take effect only in an instance of a class and not globally?

Tags: php, oop, error-handling

consider this code:

```
class TestClass {
  function __construct() {
    set_error_handler(array($this,'error_handler'));
  }
  function error_handler($errno,$errstr,$errfile,$errline,$errcontext) {
    trigger_error("\ncode: [$errno]\nfile: [$errfile -> $errline]\nSTR: [$errstr]",E_USER_ERROR);
  }
}

count($nonExistentVariable);
//notice was thrown above but script carry on
//but here error handler is registered and...
$anInstance = new TestClass();
// rest of the code is affected by it
count($nonExistentVariable); // user error is thrown
```

So is there a way to make the `error_handler` function to fire only when error is encountered inside an instance and do not mess globally with other code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the call stack in your error handler (via `debug_backtrace()`) and determine if it's coming from within the class you're interested in. If it's not coming from the class be sure to `return FALSE` and PHP will fall back on it's default handler.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php